# Too many Thread was being aborted exception asp.net

Tags: asp.net, exception

In my asp.net website error logs shows too many "Thread was being aborted" exception.
I am using framework 3.5. No Response.Redirect or Response.End used in the website. There are 2-3 async calls in the website. The mostly all error occurred in a function where SQL adaptor is feeling data. 
This errors occurs only on live server. It is private server. there are 100 active users at any point of time.

I am not able to reproduce on development PC. so not able to solve it. 
Can anybody please suggest any possible reasons which i should check.

Thanks